# Use input of purrr's map function to create a named list as output in R

Tags: r, list, named, purrr

I am using the map function of the purrr package in R which gives as output a list. Now I would like the output to be a named list based on the input. An example is given below.

```
input <- c("a", "b", "c")
output <- purrr::map(input, function(x) {paste0("test-", x)})
```

From this I would like to access elements of the list using:

```
output$a
```

Or

```
output$b
```

Comment: This is done by default by `base::Map`: `output2 <- Map(function(x) {paste0("test-", x)}, input)` .

Answer (score 43, accepted):

We just need to name the `list`

```
names(output) <- input
```

and then extract the elements based on the name

```
output$a
#[1] "test-a"
```

---

If this needs to be done using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
output <- map(input, ~paste0('test-', .)) %>% 
                                setNames(input)
```

Comment: FYI `purrr` imports `set_names()` from `rlang` for this reason. Not that there is any significant difference between `base::setNames()`...

Comment: @AndersSwanson There are significant differences, and in particular you can do `x %>% set_names() %>% map(fn)` which is the recommended solution to this problem.

Answer (score 39):

[The recommended solution:](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/691#issuecomment-540944892)

```
c("a", "b", "c") %>% 
    purrr::set_names() %>% 
    purrr::map(~paste0('test-', .))
```

Comment: Brilliant. We set the name in advance. This also works with *map_dfc*, and avoids the "renaming warnings for the duplicate names" that I get when setting the name after the map.

Answer (score 30):

**Update**

Now in 2020 the answer form @mihagazvoda describes the correct approach: simply `set_names` before applying `map`

```
c("a", "b", "c") %>% 
    purrr::set_names() %>% 
    purrr::map(~paste0('test-', .))
```

**Outdated answer**

The accepted solution works, but suffers from a repeated argument (`input`) which may cause errors and interrupts the flow when using piping with `%>%`.

An alternative solution would be to use a bit more power of the `%>%` operator

```
1:5 %>% { set_names(map(., ~ .x + 3), .) } %>% print # ... or something else
```

This takes the argument from the pipe but still lacks some beauty. An alternative could be a small helper method such as

```
map_named = function(x, ...) map(x, ...) %>% set_names(x)

1:5 %>% map_named(~ .x + 1)
```

This already looks more pretty and elegant. And would be my preferred solution.

Finally, we could even overwrite `purrr::map` in case the argument is a character or integer vector and produce a named list in such a case.

```
map = function(x, ...){
    if (is.integer(x) | is.character(x)) {
        purrr::map(x, ...) %>% set_names(x)
    }else {
        purrr::map(x, ...) 
    }
}

1 : 5 %>% map(~ .x + 1)
```

However, the optimal solution would be if `purrr` would implement such behaviour out of the box.

Comment: That would be awesome! Shouldn't you propose such a pull request? Or have they a good reason not to do this that way?

Comment: My gut feeling would be, that the `purrr` maintainers do not like it because it creates different semantics depending on the input. I'd imagine that they prefer some more explicit approach, like with a parameter, but this would support the usecase as well. Also, it would break backward compatibility in quite a few cases I guess. But sure, why not asking, see https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/691

Comment: The recommended solution (added a year later by @mihagazvoda) shows there is indeed a purrrring way of doing this.

Comment: Indeed. I don't want to delete the answer, but rather cast the upvotes to this answer to @mihagazvoda. Is there a stackoverflow way to do so?